# Building against ancient C Object

Tags: c, gcc

I have a project I'm working on that has code from 1988 and is on Solaris Sparc machines.

I'm not a C programmer, but there is a header file and object file for the old code but no sourcecode.

I can live without it, if I can use the functions in the old object file to plug stuff into and prod the outputs.

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -Wall -o test main.c
```

Outputs

```
Undefined                       first referenced
symbol                             in file
KES_ld_kb                           /var/tmp//cccjn5UP.o
```

Is there anything I can do to get gcc to build against the object so I can run some of this old code?

-- Edit --

got asked what the code looks like:

```
#include "kes.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    KES_ld_kb("/tmp/kb.kb", 50000L);
    return 0;
}
```

-- Another Edit --

I have original .o and .h files, these are SPARC based and I'm doing my work on an old SPARC VM, so that much I do know.

I tried to create an archive with

`ar ruv libkes.a kes.o`

Which when I then build it returns

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/sfw/bin/gcc -L/export/home/zmmyks/ps -Wall -o test main.c -lkes

ld: warning: file /export/home/zmmyks/ps/libkes.a ignored: unable to locate archive symbol table
```

Comment: *What* code? You can't expect us to be able to diagnose the problem with more detail, including a minimal example of what you're working with that fails.

Comment: I'm not sure how the code helps the question, literally just calling a function from this old object & header. Is this not a compilation question? The code just has the object included:

#include "kes.h"

Comment: What do you mean "old object"? Your `gcc` command isn't linking against anything.

Comment: You aren't including your object file in the build process as far as I can see.

Comment: Unless you have `.c` source for `KES_ld_kb` or a static library *that matches the architecture you're building on* then this won't work. That is an old SPARC binary won't help if you're building for x86_64.

Comment: Yeah I have a SPARC VM running and I'm building the code on that box.

I did try and create a .a library:

`ar ruv libkes.a kes.o` and then build with `gcc -L/export/home/zmmyks/ps -Wall -o test main.c -lkes` which in turn then says `libkes.a ignored: unable to locate archive symbol table`

Comment: When you say "object file", what do you mean exactly? Do you have a `.o`, `.so`, `.a` (i.e. a relocatable object file that you can link to)? Or, do you have a standalone executable? What are the pathnames?

Comment: Thanks folks, added a bit more context to the question to answer those questions and some further tinkering.

Comment: Have you tried telling GCC to actually use the obj file????? `/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -Wall -o test main.c kes.o` <- with `kes.o`

Comment: That gives the same linker warning: `ld: warning: file kes.o ignored: unable to locate archive symbol table` Sad times..

Comment: @TomBarber Have you considered using a decompiler, like ghidra, to reverse-engineer the binary? I don't know if it would work for this architecture, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you can live without the implementation of functions. A header file serves as a *blueprint* for the source, but it is not a *replacement* for it. If `KES_ld_kb` is defined in those missing source files you need to track those down or this will never work.

Comment: That's assuming the object file isn't sufficient. You should try to find the source file anyway of course. It will be easier.

Comment: @user253751 Without source I have a lot of doubts some dusty 22-year-old binary will work.

Comment: Yeah, we're trying to find the source, but I'm not holding out much hope, it was written by a company in the 80's and integrated as a dependency into some software we're moving from SPARC to X86. I don't plan to keep the old software, I just need to check what our software used to call so I can verify the inputs and outputs.

Comment: If you're moving cross-platform, switching architectures, you need the source. The headers alone are insufficient.

Comment: @TomBarber  , looks like it is K expert system (thus KES), with .kb being "knowledge base".  Made by Unisys? http://www.freepatentsonline.com/5225978.html